# WCF bindings/security configuration for Intranet that uses Mac and Windows?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-configuration

What bindings and security configurations are best for an environment with Windows and Mac Computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx) will probably have the greatest reach. Just about every platform supports it, since the data is simply sent as an HTTP POST to a specific Uri -- any platform which has a web browser can use this binding.

You can do an HTTPs binding with [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx) as well -- so you can still secure your data. You can also use security like TransportWithMessageCredential to provide username/password validation.

Answer (score 1):

The bindings depend entirely on what client software is talking to the service, and not what type of computer it's running on. What's available to the Mac client?

The security configuration depends on the binding, how the service is hosted, the environment... the question is so vague that it can't be answered right now.